# Are questions about ethics too subjective for this site?

Tags: discussion, questions

Completely wrong (though I suppose in some sense that's subjective so who cares right?) to close this

[Epistemic failure and blaming others](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/97967/epistemic-failure-and-blaming-others)

Are questions about normative judgments too subjective for this site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that if questions like these are posed as open questions, not restricted to particular ethical frameworks or authors, they indeed tend to invite opinions.

Without something particular that you have to build an answer upon, a field as wide as ethics means everyone will simply answer with whatever *they* deem correct. Even if they strengthen their answer with quotes and references, they normally do not do it in an objectified way. They tend to write "This and this is correct, see author X" (which reflects not much more than their opinion) instead of "According to author X, one could say that.." - That these question are often answered with opinions is an empirical fact.

Hence, questions as wide and open, posed to be answered by *a whole branch* of philosophy, are often closed as inviting opinions or needing focus. Both reasons are valid.

Comment: i see what you mean, but your second paragraph seem more pedantic than it does helpful. anyway, doesn't seem too broad. does every ethical discussion have to limit itself to an ethical framework before it starts?

Comment: @zero It seems you have no idea just how vast ethical literature and the variety of positions is. There is no way to properly answer the question beyond personal opinion. The alternative is basically writing a book.

Comment: i can guess that there are 1000s of ethics phds today and so by extension 100,000s of articles in the world. find me one that answer the question ONE

Comment: that may sound counter intuitive, but TRUST ME. i have been using this site for a decade, asking questions, googling and generally making a nuisance of myself. i cannot find an answer through google: this is what i do

Comment: @zero You won't find one *because it needs quite a thick book to find a substantial answer, considering at least the most important arguments*. That is pretty much the point.

Comment: ha i see what you mean, sorry. what a useless hobby D:

Comment: it's a strange use of downtime, trying to use a question and answer site to clarify what answers there are on google

Comment: @zero Well, in a sense, you can find a lot of answers to everything. The point of StackExchange is not to find *any* answer though, it is to find *a correct, objective, and ideally exhaustive* answer. That's the main point of why we moderate questions much heavier than other sites, because the question sets the tone for possible answers.

Comment: yes ofc, and i am at best concerned by the subjective nature of a lot of answers, so thanks. incidentally, chat gpt claimed to know the answer, and i asked for a quote, from locke, and it completely botched the idea (right to property magically becomes duty to share knowledge). though i suppose modelling knowledge on property rights might help an answer (i mean find one through google)